# navigation bar hides on resturning back to search controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

on opening search controller navigation bar shows but whenever tab is switched and get returns to search controller navigation bar got hides.

I have tried

but nothing is happening.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated

{

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];;
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

 }
```

[image: initially when search bar tapped for search results]

[image: after returning from another tab]

Comment: why you asked the same question in repeatly

Comment: because i am not getting answer from anywhere.. And in last question I didn't add the images. So here for clarity I posted the images also

Comment: check once you were hided anywhere in your app

Comment: I checked .. I didn't hide it anywhere else

Comment: ok , are you dismissed the current view controller correct, on that place use present view controller once and check

Comment: try to put it under viewWillAppear too...

Comment: [this will help you](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=navigation%20bar%20with%20search%20bar%20hiding) check first three links...